# Export SQL data to a predefined Excel printing format and put it on intranet

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

Previously, I created a SSRS report and set the report properties to landscape, tabloid and 17 x 11 printing format. When user goes online and ran the report and export it to Excel the predefined printing format did not take place. I do not think SSRS cannot invoke the Excel printing format. I need something that I can place Excel on intranet and can call a view or stored procedure for user to export it with my predefined printing format. Also on the report I have group by section and bold the line on each new group. Can this be done on Excel? Any recommendation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing the data into Excel via SSRS, you might consider pulling the data into a pre-formatted Excel sheet with Microsoft Query. The Excel file would sit somewhere on your intranet that a user can access, and when they open the file they can refresh the data: it does require a bit more training for the user.

[Use Microsoft Query to retrieve external data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e)